# AWS IAM user console password last updated API

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I was not able to find an AWS API for when the console password was last updated for an IAM user.

IAM user `getLoginProfile` method provides with data on whether the password is enabled. Response is NULL if there is no console password for that user.

`getLoginProfile().createDate` will provide the date when the FIRST password was created for that user and not when the most recent password was created.

I was not able to find a boto3/Java AWS API for my work. Is it a limitation from AWS?

Note: I can see from AWS console when the password was last updated, so AWS must be using some API behind the scenes to get that data on their console UI.

Comment: I think you can try AWS cloudtrail events to get the history

Comment: Thanks, but my application (Access provisioning and management) doesn't have permissions to read from CloudTrail.

Comment: You can generate credentials report with the APIs and then extract password last changed

Answer (score 1):

You can [generate credential report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GenerateCredentialReport.html) and then [get credential report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialReport.html), which will be a csv with `password_last_changed` field.  Here is the [IAM documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_getting-report.html) on this.